# Angular froala integration

Tags: angularjs, module, froala

I am not able to inject **froala** wysiwyg-editor dependency to my module.
It shows this error:

```
Failed to instantiate module froala due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/nomod?p0=froala
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:6:412
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:25:235
    at b (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:24:282)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:25:20
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:39:374
    at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:39:222)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:39:391
    at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:7:355
```

My module in app.js is:

```
var teacherDashboard = angular.module('teacherDashboard', ['froala','ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngRoute', 'angularCSS']);
```

and the main index.html head contains:

```
<head>

    <title>
        Teacher Dashboard
    </title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-css/1.0.8/angular-css.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <!--floara editor-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.3.4/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.3.4/css/froala_editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.3.4/css/froala_style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!------>
    <script src="./scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/services/service.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/controllers/selectTopics.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/controllers/selectTest.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/controllers/assignQuestionNo.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/controllers/assignTeachers.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/controllers/reviewPanel.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/teacherDashboard.css">
    <!--    <base href="/">-->
</head>
```

I am following this link for refernce [LINK](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/angular1)
Where am i possibly going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing the "froala" angular module in your index.html
Here is the link of the module :  [angular-froala.js](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/blob/master/src/angular-froala.js)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out... I thought including the cdn provided in the documentation would suffice. But I had to download the github zip file and put it in my project folder to make it work. :)

Comment: @jAYANTYADAV how did It work. do I need to extract the zip? and in which folder should it place?

Comment: @Shubham inside the project folder. your src will now point to this local .js file.