# Adding Froala breaks Karma Unit Tests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner, froala

I've just added Froala to my Angularjs (1.5) project via bower install and it's breaking the unit tests I currently have setup. When I add 'froala' to the angular.module being defined in app.js it breaks the tests, but all of the tests pass when I remove it.

**I have Froala configured in an app.js file:**

`angular.module('app', [ 'froala',....`

**I'm referencing the local/downloaded files in index.html**

```
<link href="bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/css/froala_editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/css/froala_style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/js/angular-froala.js"></script>
```

**And this is the error I'm getting:**

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ctrl.disableInput')`

Here's the [Karma configuration](https://gist.github.com/leroygreene/dd9bdb6352bbd6f5b0052b051916e05f) and an [example test](https://gist.github.com/leroygreene/b2cec8047f314e65be39fe84602a5fe5) that's passing prior to adding froala.

Is there something in Froala that I need to configure in order to have passing tests?

Comment: There isn't any code here. the general problem is something isn't being loaded.

Comment: Thanks @AluanHaddad. Right, it seems as though something isn't being loaded simply by adding 'froala' into the array because the tests are running otherwise. I'm wondering if the issue is with a configuration I may be mishandling or overlooking

Comment: Can you add the code that bootstraps your tests and your test configuration?

Comment: Thanks @AluanHaddad, I've updated the question to include my test configuration

Comment: What happens if you remove the path to the angular mocks library from the files config? remove `'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'` and see

Comment: When I remove the mocks library I still get the same TypeError.

Comment: I should have told you to remove the path to angular itself.  what I'm getting at is that you probably need to load it explicitly _before_ your app but _after_ angular

Comment: This is sort of organization, where interdependent files have no relationship and depend on load ordering that can easily break or worse, can be avoided by using a module system. That is a big step however

Comment: Okay thanks. I've tried a couple of combinations - removing just the path to angular itself and removing all of the paths related to angular, i.e., material, ui-mask, and ui-router. It returns the same TypeError

Comment: It's load ordering. Your script tags load `angular-frola` after its dependencies. That's brittle but it works. You need to know all interdependencies to make it work.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'll look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple mistake on my part by loading angular-froala within the bower components folder. This part `src="bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/js/angular-froala.js"` and including it within app.js `angular.module('app', [ 'froala',....`. I removed both of these references and only have this in the index:

```
<link href="bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/css/froala_editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />. 
<link href="bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/css/froala_style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />. 
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script>.
```

I followed this previous stack overflow answer regarding [integrating with angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890789/angular-froala-integration) and assumed I needed to include it, but it wasn't necessary.